# XSLT counting position and group items accordingly

Tags: c#, html, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I have some input XML which is

```
<collection>
    <content>
        <id>10</id>
        <type>xx</type>
        <title>xx</title>
        <quicklink>xx</quicklink>
        <teaser><p>xxx</p></teaser>
        <root>
            <thumb><img src="/xxx/xxx.jpg" /></thumb>
            <link>http://www.foo.com</link>
        </root>
        <startDate></startDate>
        <enddate></enddate>
        <hyperlink><a href="http://www.foo.com">some text</a></hyperlink>
    </content>
    <content>
        <id>10</id>
        <type>xx</type>
        <title>xx</title>
        <quicklink>xx</quicklink>
        <teaser><p>xxx</p></teaser>
        <root>
            <thumb><img src="/xxx/xxx.jpg" /></thumb>
            <link>http://www.foo.com</link>
        </root>
        <startDate></startDate>
        <enddate></enddate>
        <hyperlink><a href="http://www.foo.com">some text</a></hyperlink>
    </content>
    <content>
        <id>10</id>
        <type>xx</type>
        <title>xx</title>
        <quicklink>xx</quicklink>
        <teaser><p>xxx</p></teaser>
        <root>
            <thumb><img src="/xxx/xxx.jpg" /></thumb>
            <link>http://www.foo.com</link>
        </root>
        <startDate></startDate>
        <enddate></enddate>
        <hyperlink><a href="http://www.foo.com">some text</a></hyperlink>
    </content>
</collection>
```

XSLT written to format an unordered list as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul id="case-study-icons">
      <xsl:for-each select="collection/content">
        <li>
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/Link"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title">
              <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <img>
              <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/thumb/img/@src"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="width">92</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="height">46</xsl:attribute>
            </img>
          </a>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I would like to change this to have 3 image links inside one `li and grounp every 3 item occurance into 3 image links groups wrapped with`li`. So at the end of the transformation the HTML must look like below

```
<ul id="case-study-icons">
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
        <a href="#"><img src="/foo.jpg" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I did try to do this myself using `position()` somehow my logic seems not working. Can someone please have a look? Many thanks in Advance..

Comment: I have a current XSLT already written as above. Currently, it outputs 1 image link per "li". I would like to change it to 3 image links per "li". Input to XSL is a .NET list of objects.

Comment: I mean XML input on which you apply transformation.

Comment: I unfortunately don't have that information. The items are rendered via a control which I don't have access to. :-(

Comment: Apply this XSLT `<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>` to see original XML.

Comment: Added to the question at the top. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Select every third `Content` element then start the `li` element, then within that select the three elements you need. It wasn't clear if your `Content` elements were siblings so I used `following` rather than `following-sibling`

```
  <xsl:for-each select="(Collection/Content)[position() mod 3 = 1]">
    <li>
       <xsl:for-each select=".|following::Content[position() &lt; 3]">
            <a href="{Html/root/Link}" title="{Title}">
               <img src="{Html/root/Thumb/img/@src}" alt="{Title}/>
             </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
   </li>
 </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Thanks David, for some reason above doesn't display anything on the page meaning there's something wring with the above XSLT.

Comment: ah well it would help if it had as many `[` as `]` on the first line. Will update.

Comment: It's still the same unless you haven't updated it. the XML input is at the top if it's any help.

Comment: Your input file has elements collection and content but your proposed xslt has Collection/Content with capital C. XML is case sensitive, If that _is_ your input file then your original code did not produce the output that you indicated, so the change suggested will not make the intended change. You need to post a sample input, preferably with more than 3 items and using the correct element names. (or just change your xslt to match the names in your input)

Comment: XML above was copied from Firebug output and was put on the page with @Kirill Polishchuk suggestion above. The XSLT above is what's on the code and I have simply copied it from Visual Studio. So it could be the case that Firebug render them as simple letters. I have changed your code to simple letter but sitll no luck

Comment: you need to debug by running the code outside the browser and just run it in the browser once it's working. Your sample xslt (and my variant) has a step Html/root but the xml you since showed doesn't have an html element (with any case) between the content and root elements. If the XSLT you show produces the output you show then your input is not as shown, which makes it impossible to help, sorry.

Comment: Thanks David, I have kinda answere my question with the help of yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Kindly David had pointed me at the right direction and I have managed to come to the correct transformation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <ul id="case-study-icons">
      <xsl:for-each select="(Collection/Content)[position() mod 3 = 1]">
        <li style="width:100px; float:left;">
        <xsl:for-each select=".|following-sibling::Content[position() &lt; 3]">
          <a>
            <xsl:attribute name="href">
              <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/Link"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:attribute name="title">
              <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <img>
              <xsl:attribute name="src">
                <xsl:value-of select="Html/root/Thumb/img/@src"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="alt">
                <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="width">92</xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:attribute name="height">46</xsl:attribute>
            </img>
          </a>
        </xsl:for-each>
        </li>
      </xsl:for-each>
      </ul>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might want to parameterise the number of items per group, rather than hard-code the **3**. Additionally, it could be possibly be simplified, by firstly avoiding the need for nested **xsl:for-each**, and secondly by the use of Attribute Value Templates to write out attributes

Try this XSLT, for example

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:param name="itemsperlist" select="3" />

   <xsl:template match="/collection">
      <ul id="case-study-icons">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="content[(position() - 1) mod $itemsperlist = 0]" mode="first" />
      </ul>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="content" mode="first">
      <li>
         <xsl:apply-templates select=".|following-sibling::content[position() &lt; $itemsperlist]" />
      </li>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="content">
      <a href="{root/link}" title="{title}">
         <img src="{root/thumb/img/@src}" alt="{title}" width="92" height="46" />
      </a>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that this solution would work if you changed the **3** to a **1**.